# Sequentially show multiple dialogs?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I'm new to Android and I'm programing an application with multiple user interfaces(windows).
I find it a little hard to define new activity for each window so I end up with using Dialogs more than activity. But there is a scenario where **I need to sequentially show multiple dialogs**.
In c# showing Dialog is blocking operation. But I don't know how to do that in Android.
**if there, I welcome any alternatives**.

Comment: do you mean, closing on one dialog should display the next one?

Comment: yes open one dialog get data from user do some process the launch the other dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a sequence of dialog, you can use the onclick listeners. From one dialog, open the following one. ( [dialog interface for the listeners](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html))
and if you want to block your program, so the user has to click on the dialog, set the dialogs not cancelable ([setCancelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29))

Answer (score 1):

OK with no code reference I would say the easiest way would be using [ondimiss listeners](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html) in each dialog for the next one to be called.  You can check out this short example to get an idea of implementation (note they are using ondismiss for something else).

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/11/cancel-progressdialog.html